# send (java) parameter using email by shell script

Tags: java, shell, servlets

I'm using servlet as backend i got this code to get all the parameter from my form :

```
public void doPost (HttpServletRequest _httpReq, HttpServletResponse _httpRes) throws IOException, ServletException
{
  try
    {
      _httpRes.setContentType("text/html");
      PrintWriter out = _http.getWriter();
      String message = "";
      enumeration<String> paramNames = _httpReq.getParameterNames();

      while(paramNames.hasMoreElements())
      {
        String paramName = paramNames.nextElement();
        String[] paramValues = _httpReq.getParameterValues(paramName);
        for (int i=0; i < paramValues.length; i++)
        {
          String paramValue = paramValues[i];
          message = message + paramName + " - " + paramValue + "\n";
      . . .
```

i want to send an email that contains `message` parameter.

i can use this script to send mail `echo "test mail" | /usr/bin/swaks --to email@gmail.com` but i have no idea how to send my `message` there. How can i send it?

Comment: use a browser plugin

Comment: @ScaryWombat browser plugin?